# Code First Data Annotations and Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class like this:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GazetteerLinks> GazetteerLinks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

and it is inherited by between 1 and n sub - classes. Is there a way that I can disable the Required annotation on some of the sub - classes? I'm not 100% sure that all data sets coming from third parties will be able to meet the requirement, but would like to enforce it on data sets that I am creating myself.

Comment: You could try overriding the property in the subclass. I'm not sure that will remove the required or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a comment and an answer for you on this.

The comment: That `Required` annotation has no business being there in the case that you're describing. If you're giving access to 3rd parties and are not sure that they will require those properties then you need to make them nullable. For your own data sets I would highly recommend having a ViewModel object and then slapping some validation on that object, and only after it passes validation create the database object and save it to the database. That way you get the best of both worlds: You don't have to worry about the 3rd party not requiring it, and your own work will require the validation.

The answer: I had a similar situation with a project that I've been working on recently. What I ended up doing was making that class an abstract class and then overriding the value in the subclass. If you override the property and have different annotations EF is smart enough to know to only look at the override for making the table.

Comment: Appreciate the real world example, I will give what you suggested a try. I accept what you say about making them nullable but it's always nice to have two different approaches to something.